# Add commands in a loop procedure while it is running

Tags: tcl

My goal is to add commands to a loop that is already running , I know how to do it with global variables like this :

```
proc myLoop {} {
   global cmd1 cmd2 cmd3
   if {$cmd1} {
       # do something...
   }
   if {$cmd2} {
       # do something...
   }
   # ...
   
   after 1000 myLoop
}

set cmd1 0 ; set cmd2 1
myLoop
```

I’d like to do this on the fly :
`addCmdInLoop [list myCmd $arg1 $arg2]` . I had thought to rename my `myLoop` every time and replace it but I don’t know if this is possible or efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your commands in a list and process that list every time. To add a command, just append it to the list.

```
proc myLoop {} {
    global cmdlist
    foreach cmd $cmdlist {
        # Execute the command in the global scope
        uplevel #0 $cmd
    }
    after 1000 myLoop
}
set cmdlist [list $cmd1 $cmd2]
# Start the loop
myLoop
# Add a command
lappend cmdlist [list myCmd $arg1 $arg2]
```

You can also get fancy with a coroutine to avoid using a global variable:

```
proc myLoop {cmdlist} {
    foreach cmd $cmdlist {
        # Execute the command in the global scope
        uplevel #0 $cmd
    }
    after 1000 [list [info coroutine] continue]
    while {[set arg [yield]] ne "continue"} {
        lappend cmdlist $arg
    }
}
coroutine addCmdInLoop myLoop $cmd1 $cmd2
```

Then your proposed `addCmdInLoop [list myCmd $arg1 $arg2]` command will work to add myCmd to any future runs of the loop.

Comment: I've known people do this... where they pull the list of commands to call in the loop from an SQLite database each time round the loop. I don't think I ever want to write things like that myself.

Answer (score 1):

If `myLoop` is already running, then I don't know how you could interrupt the loop to change the variable.   Without changing the variable, then the loop would already act the same way.

You could certainly change some external to Tcl.  What if your loop checked for existence of a filename instead of the value of a variable?

What you probably want to do instead is to add a *trace* to these variables.
https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/trace.htm

```
proc do_cmd1 args {
    global cmd1
    if {$cmd1 == 1} {
        puts "cmd1 is 1"
    }
}
trace add variable cmd1 write do_cmd1
```

Once the trace is assigned to the variable, then the `do_cmd1` proc is executed anytime a value is written to `cmd1`.

```
tcl8.6.8> set cmd1 0
0
tcl8.6.8> set cmd1 1
cmd1 is 1    <------ Look at that!!
1
```

However, this only runs the proc when the cmd1 variable is set.   That's not really a loop behavior.

Comment: thanks I will keep your idea, for a next time..